# What format should I pass values to a Checkbox Set, in FileMaker Pro from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, filemaker

I am working for a client that uses FileMaker Pro (FMP) as their business model, and I have been working on the project which uses MySQL to Sync with FMP at particular times. However they have created a new feature in FMP that I am unsure how to insert into a box that contains options.

The box they have created has a list of options called a `checkbox set`, possibly FMPs version of a hash or an array with specific values set to on or off I would assume. In this case how would I go about passing the correct string to FMP via the [FX.php Connector](http://www.iviking.org/FX.php/).

Can I pass it to FMP as a list string like: `"var1,var2,var3,var4"` (delimited by commas) or do I need to pass it as a "new line" delimited string?

Thanks for any information you can provide me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on it (been a while since I used FX.php) but I believe new line `\r\n`will do it.

Edit:

According to [this post](http://mail.iviking.org/pipermail/fx.php_list/2006-August/002137.html) you can also do $fx->AddDBParam for each checkbox element.

Comment: Okay I will try that real quick. Thanks!

Comment: How would I do that? `Catagory::Checkbox_Set::Parameter_Name` with `_` replacing spaces?